# NodeJS Twitter api search more than 100 tweets

Tags: node.js, twitter

I have problem with my code. I want to download more than 100 tweets with one query. Is it possible to get more than 100 tweets using the Twitter API?

My code:

```
module.exports = function(text, callback) {
    console.log("Test: " + text);
    var twitterClient = new twitter(config);
    var response = [], dbData = []; // to store the tweets and sentiment

    console.log(1, twitterClient.search);

    twitterClient.search(text, {count: 500}, function(data) {

        console.log("Obiekt: " + data);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.statuses.length; i++) {
            var resp = {};


            resp.tweet = data.statuses[i];
            resp.sentiment = sentimentAnalysis(data.statuses[i].text);
            dbData.push({
                tweet: resp.tweet.text,
                score: resp.sentiment.score
            });
            response.push(resp);
        };
        db.sentiments.save(dbData);
        callback(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) its updated lib, If answer helped you in anyway please mark it correct.

Comment: Why limit yourself to just one query? You can get well over a thousand tweets with several queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No** Its not allowed by twitter api. `count: 100` is max limit.

> count optional
>
> The number of tweets to return per page, up to a maximum of 100.
>   Defaults to 15. This was formerly the “rpp” parameter in the old
>   Search API.
>
> Example Values: 100

[Search Api Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets)

Answer (score 1):

Although **it is not technically allowed by the Twitter API to query more than 100 tweets at once**, that only acounts for tweets in a single query, which means **you could technically make a query, fetch 100 tweets, push them to an array, then repeat the query** with the `max_id` parameter set to the lowest ID you had in your previous query, and push that to the array again, and so on.

The limit for this approach would be 18000 / 15min or 45000 / 15min if you're using app auth.